# VSCode "Open With Code" in explorer menu throws error

Tags: visual-studio-code

After reinstalling vscode because I forgot to add it to start menu, 
whenever I clicked "open with code" after right clicking in explorer menu, it gave me this error:
"Application not found"

I told vscode to add this option in explorer when installing!

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after a reinstall of VS Code. I had switched from the User Installer to the System Installer version.

The install didn't update the registry to change the Icon and "Open with Code" context menu to use the new System path to Code.exe.

So you have a couple options. Reinstall your initial version (User vs System) or update your registry anywhere Code.exe is referenced.

**User path**: *C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe*

**System path**: *C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe*

Or perhaps even uninstall, clear out the references to Code.exe in your Registry, then install the version you'd like